# Listing in a array variables id's generated randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have the following html/script:

```
<div id="firstDiv" class="first">1
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<div id="secondDiv" class="second">2
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<button class="1st">show 1st</button>
<button class="2nd">show 2nd</button>
```

JS:

```
localStorage.clear();

$(document).on('click', ':checkbox', function () {
    var div = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).closest("div").addClass('hilight marked');
        localStorage.setItem(div, true);
    } else {
        $(this).closest("div").removeClass('hilight marked');
        localStorage.setItem(div, false);
    }
});

$(".1st").on('click', function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem("firstDiv") == "true") {
        $(".first").closest("div").addClass('hilight');
    }
    $(".second").css('display', 'none').removeClass('hilight');
    $(".first").css('display', 'block');
});

$(".2nd").on('click', function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem("secondDiv") == "true") {
        $(".second").closest("div").addClass('hilight');
    }
    $(".first").css('display', 'none').removeClass('hilight');
    $(".second").css('display', 'block');
});
```

I'm creating a "var" to get the Id's of divs and setting it on LocalStorage.
After that i'm telling my js to if it has the item "firstDiv" at storage, add a class "hilight".

My problem is: I don't know exactly what ID's the divs will have, because it's generated randomly by my back-end system (java).

Any suggestions ? http://jsfiddle.net/b4KgV/11/

Comment: So you want to know how to access element's `id` related to clicked button? You can use `$(".first").attr("id")` for 1st button and `$(".second").attr("id")` for the 2nd. Is that what youre asking?

Comment: no. I updated the fiddle with comments for better understanding. http://jsfiddle.net/b4KgV/12/

Comment: The one you post doesnt has comment but this(http://jsfiddle.net/b4KgV/14/) one does. And only change is instead of bg change now it's alerting. I dont get the real difference. And take a look at [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/b4KgV/17/). It's not using ids directly. That was what i meant

Comment: @BatuZet http://jsfiddle.net/b4KgV/19/